Why is downloading a file from a webserver using HTTP faster than transferring it locally using R(eliable)UDP?
So I downloaded this 1gb file from here and it took about 20-30 seconds (I was using wget not sure if it matters).
Then I tried transferring the file using a Python script that implements Namuyan's Reliable UDP, here are the scripts:
sender.py
from srudp import SecureReliableSocket
from time import sleep, time
from tqdm import tqdm
import os

# Initialize the socket
sock = SecureReliableSocket()
sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", 12345))

# Read the file to send
filename = '1gb'
file_size = os.path.getsize(filename)
data = open(filename, 'rb').read()

# Initialize tqdm progress bar
with tqdm(total=file_size, unit='B', unit_scale=True, desc='Sending', leave=True) as pbar:
    sock.sendall(data)
    sent_bytes = len(data)
    print(sent_bytes)
    pbar.update(sent_bytes)
    sleep(3)  # Ensure this doesn't slow down the sending process
    sock.sendall(b'SOCK_CLOSE_SIG')
    print("closed", sock)

receiver.py
from srudp import SecureReliableSocket
from time import time
from tqdm import tqdm
import os

# Initialize the socket
sock = SecureReliableSocket()
sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", 12345))

# Define the expected file size (should be known or transferred)
filename = '1gb2'
file_size = 1073741824  # Example file size of 10 MB

# Initialize tqdm progress bar
with tqdm(total=file_size, unit='B', unit_scale=True, desc='Receiving', leave=True) as pbar:
    final_data = b''
    while not sock.is_closed:
        data = sock.recv(4096)
        if not data:
            break

        elif b'SOCK_CLOSE_SIG' in data:
            final_data += data.replace(b'SOCK_CLOSE_SIG', b'')
            print(len(final_data), end='\r')
            break
        final_data += data
        # print(len(final_data), end='\r')
        pbar.update(len(data))

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(final_data)
    print("closed", sock)

and it gave me an ETA of 1 to 2 hours, as I am typing this it is at 7% and it is running since 10 minutes.
Why is this happening? doesn't HTTP use TCP? Isn't UDP supposed to be faster furthermore when it is running on the local network?
By the way another strange thing I noticed that when I did a speed comparison between HTTP, RUDP and TCP; HTTP was the fastest (webserver), then TCP (local) and after that RUDP (local). So when RUDP was supposed to be the fastest it turned out to be the slowest???

TCP and UDP transfer data at the same rate on the same interface. It is the addition of reliability that can slow TCP compared to UDP. If you only use UDP (fire-and-forget with no expectation that data are received), then UDP is faster. Adding in an upper-layer reliability, especially using a slow interpreted language, then, yes, UDP can be much slower. TCP has been tweaked over the years to be reliable at a pretty fast rate, so tying to recreate that reliability on your own may not be faster.

I agree with the comments above, related to the networking protocol comparison, but in case this is a real world problem you need to solve, here's a broader answer.
Why is x faster than y?
The answer is: you won't know the real answer unless you do end-to-end perf testing.
Besides network concerns, there might be bottlenecks on either end, like disk I/O and how the process behaves.
How long will it take?
You sound concerned about the time estimate, but before you worry about it too much, you should look carefully at the way the ETA is calculated. Of all things I've tested (pretty much most internet software except modern AI), the display of a download progress and ETA is one of the most difficult problems to solve.
For example: you've said the ETA is 1-2 hours. To some, this would be unacceptably vague (almost at +100% possible delay). But given you said 10% over 7 minutes, that is ~70 minutes, which makes the range of the ETA seem reasonable... esp if you think that data transfer rates can go down, but can't go faster than a practical limit.
